# Examples of self hosted cartodb implementations

Tags: carto, hosting, implementation

I am very impressed with the ease of use of CartoDB and the fact that it is based on OGC standards. I think it would be very usefull for none-GIS specialists. However, I would like to know how well it is suited for internal use. Also because we already have many OpenGIS-services available and we would like to host our own data.

Therefore I'm searching for examples of self hosted implementations of CartoDB.

Please let me know if you know organisations who have done their own implementation of CartoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any exmaples of self hosted implementations and maybe one of the main reasons for that is it is a bit tricky to install. However, at FOSS4G13 in Nottingham, Javier de la Torre from CartoDB, ran through CartoDB's platform and some of their other tools like Torque. He put up the workshop content on his GitHub

https://github.com/jatorre/foss4g_workshop

But one of the key things he mentioned that might help you is they are working on simplifying how to deploy CartoDB for yourself. Rather than have to install a lot of dependencies and software that your company might not understand or allow you to install, they are going to try and create simple binaries. It might be worth getting in touch and find out how they are getting on with that.